# GAE: Submit task from one service to be executed by another service

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a GAE app with a Python3 service (the default) and a NodeJS18 service.

I currently submit App Engine tasks (not HTTP target tasks) from the Python3 service and those tasks are executed by that same Python3 service.  I have a `default` task queue where those tasks are submitted.

Now, I would like to submit a task from the Python3 service and have it executed by the NodeJS18 service.

I'm using the `google.cloud.tasks_v2` Python client to submit tasks.  You can select the queue to submit the task to, but I don't see a way to specify which GAE service should process the task.  Is it possible to specify the service to process the task?

If I instead submit the task from the NodeJS18 service to the same default queue, will it then be executed by the NodeJS18 service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any mention of 'service' in the documentation.

Given that you have to specify the `relative_uri` (this is the route that will handle the task), I think the following are possible ways to achieve your aim

1. If your `dispatch.yaml` file only routes based on paths (no domain is mentioned), then I think that just specifying the path as the value for the `relative_uri` should get it routed to the correct service.

   - e.g you have

   ```
       - url: "*/mobile/*"
        service: mobile-frontend

       - url: "*/work/*"
        service: static-backend
   ```

   I think that if you just specify `/mobile/mobile_task` as the relative_uri for the task when being called from `/work/page-1`, it should get routed to the mobile-frontend service.

**[NOTE: Haven't tried this option myself]**

2. If your `dispatch.yaml` file routing includes domains/subdomains, then you could possibly first execute an HTTP call (e.g a POST) to the url of the target service (at a specific route) and that route will then submit the task e.g.

   - Say you have a service reached at `blog.example.com`. This is the service you wish to process a task submitted from your `default` service
   - From a different (default) service, you make an HTTP call to `blog.example.com/prep_task_invocation/` and pass the data for the task to be executed
   - `blog.example.com/prep_task_invocation/` will then submit the task to itself (the current process you have) assuming the `relative_uri` won't get it routed to another service

Comment: Yeah, I think that would work but it adds a lot complication for something relatively simple.

Comment: Task submission seems to be independent of the service that submitted it.  A task submitted by the blog service will be handled by the default service unless you have something in dispatch.yaml to route it to the blog service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution I'm working on.

Use an `HTTP target task`

I'm trying an `HTTP target task` but ran into the issue that you can't change retry options with an `HTTP target task` despite the google docs suggesting it can be done.  Super frustrating.