# Why are GAE appspot URLs routed to the default service?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am deploying 3 different instances of my python/django application as 3 different services within my project.

- app-devl as a shared dev environment
- app-test as a test environment
- default for the production environment

I have a custom domain aliases mapped to the various services via the dispatch.yaml (devl.myapp.com, test.myapp.com, and myapp.com).  These all work just fine.

But the 'built-in' appspot URLs for each service appear to be routed to the default service.

As per the documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed, URLs with this format: https://SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com should be routed to the specified service, but that just isn't happening.  Both of these URLs (with the correct service-id) are being routed to the default service:

- app-devl-dot-{project-id}.nn.r.appspot.com
- app-test-dot-{project-id}.nn.r.appspot.com

Even clicking on the service in the GAE console (https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services) appears to be routed to the default service.

While users can go to the custom domain and hit the correct environment, other google cloud services (e.g. Cloud Tasks) that target a specific service use the appspot URLs and those are being routed to the wrong environment.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Confirm you have the right service names in the URL. As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#soft_routing) says, if the service doesn't exist, it will get routed to the default service. Also, I believe App Engine tasks always go to the default service (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77545935/gae-submit-task-from-one-service-to-be-executed-by-another-service/77553779?noredirect=1#comment136820754_77553779))

Comment: I can confirm that the service names are correct.  As noted, even clicking the service within the AppEngine console appears to be served by the default service.

Comment: The links work as described so something else is the problem.

Comment: ```even clicking the service within the AppEngine console appears to be served by the default service``` - does that service have a route handler for the root i.e. for ```/```?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with my dispatch.  While the documentation indicates that the appspot URLs are no affected by the dispatch rules.  Having a dispatch rule of */* affects all URLs (including the appspot URLs).